# Condition in read() function CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

In CakePHP function `edit` I use `read()` function as:

```
$this->data = $this->Article->read(null, $id);
```

It brings all fields of `$id`. Now, what I am trying to  tweak to give one more condition in `read()` to get articles only if user logged in is related to it.

eg:

```
 $this->Article->user_id = $user_id;
 $this->Article->id = $id;
 $this->Article->read();
```

And obviously it want work as [`read()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1029/read) brings data only w.r.t. `$id` (primary key).

My question:

1. Is there any way to tweak read function with condition more than `$id` ? Because it will just need to add a one line in all my controllers if it works ?
2. Or I have to use long code of find() function to get is the only option ?

Any best solution will be appreciable.

Comment: you can try to use it magick function: $this->Article->findByUserId($user_id);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really must do thise, you could use OOP techniques to override the way the core method works.

Just copy the [`Model::read()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/b1c4b57d85308e10d490688030edeaa2eaa113f5/cake/libs/model/model.php#L1102) method to your `AppModel` class and make the changes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `find()` if you want to make the search conditionally. Another option is to read the data only if the conditions hold:

```
$this->Article->id = $id;
if( $this->Article->field( 'user_id' ) == $user_id ) {
    $this->Article->read();
}
```

(`read()` populates `$this->data` automatically.)